# How many users per Android version my application has

Tags: android

I want to insert new feature in my application. This feature needs use of functions from newer API than my min supported API.

I want to know how may users I have per Android version, so I know to how many users it can cause a problem.

I didn't find a way to get this information from Android developer console.

Comment: Check your dev dashboard on Google play store.

Comment: I saw several questions about the app store in SO so I understood that this is not off-topic

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can see in the `Android Developer Console`.

Go to `Statistics`

[image: Statistics]

Select `Installs on Active Devices` and choose date range as `LifeTime`

[image: Installs on Active Devices]

Click to `+ add android version`

[image: Add Android Version]

You can see installed on active devices for each version

Comment: An image illustration would be great!!

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I can not share because there is a lot of information about the app. Needs a lot of effort for censored

Answer (score 0):

The UI has changed quite a lot now.

Select statistics -> Select "View by" -> Select Android Version -> Then select whichever version you need.

[image]