# Where in the Google Play Console can I see the Android version distribution of my app?

Tags: android, google-play-console

In the old Play Console, I was able to see what Android versions the users of my app have, like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55246731/5428154

How can I do this in the new (November 2020) Google Play Console? The old one is apparently not available anymore :(

Answer (score 46, accepted):

1. Open `Statistics` from side panel
2. In the top `Configure report` section, select `Devices > Install base > All devices`
3. Below that select `View by: Android version`
4. There you can click `+ Android version` chip

[image]

[image]

Comment: btw I think they renamed `Active devices` to `Install base` recently.

Comment: I don't know why, but this is different from user acquisition on the page

Answer (score 22):

It steel there :

1. Select 'Statistics -> Active devices -> All devices`
   [image: 1]
2. Select 'Android Version'
   [image: 2]
3. Click to + add android version
   [image: 3]

Comment: other answer was one minute faster -> i accepted the other one. thanks anyway, i still upvoted your answer - sorry for my dumb question. i just couldnt find it for 30 minutes

Answer (score 1):

If anyone couldn't find it still (like me), I could not find the "Android Versions" button.

You need to click on "View by: Country/Region" and "Android Version" should be right underneath it. Mine was set to Country/Region by default.